# What exception should I throw when code which isn't supposed to run is run?

Tags: java, exception

```
if (stuff) doThings();
else if (something) doOtherThings();
else if (otherStuff) doStuff();
else // .. this isn't supposed to be reached
```

In situations such as the one above, I like to put the `else` in the end so I can be notified if the program runs code it shouldn't run, meaning something went wrong (i.e. one of the above conditions should be true, but none are, which means something is wrong).

What exception should I throw in that final else, to notify me something is wrong?

Comment: The reason why it should not get into the else is important to answer you, it affects the semantic of the exception to be thrown.

Comment: In general, assertions are used for this kinda stuff. AssertionError might be suitable.

Comment: I think throwing an exception is not a good idea. The better approach would be to prevent such an Input. Also I would suggest if it absolutely necessary then throw a custom exception which will be appropriate for the business logic.

Comment: I use IllegalStateException for that, or create my own ShouldNeverHappenException.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`IllegalStateException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html) is a good candidate.

As the Java API states:

> Signals that a method has been invoked at an illegal or inappropriate time. In other words, the Java environment or Java application is not in an appropriate state for the requested operation.

In other words, your [program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) is in a state for which there is no transition defined for that "this isn't supposed to be reached" input.

If your `stuff`, `something` and `otherStuff` are all related to your method arguments, you could also use [`IllegalArgumentException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html), like:

```
if (arg == null) doThings();
else if (arg.endsWith("foo")) doOtherThings();
else if (arg.endsWith("bar")) doStuff();
else throw new IllegalArgumentException(
        "arg should be null or end with \"foo\" or \"bar\"");
```

Comment: I was always under impression that IllegalStateException is for situations where calling the method at that particular time is illegal, but might be legal in general. So IMO it really depends on the grade of "this should not happen": whether it is "never" or "sometimes"

Comment: @soulcheck, I like to think of `IllegalStateException` as a signal to an unexpected input for the current program state (or current "time" as the Java API states), considering the program as a [state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine): all the objects are the **state**, and the methods define the automations.

Comment: Yeah, though that definition makes it so broad that one could throw IllegalState for everything ;)

Comment: @soulcheck, well it makes it so broad that one could throw it "when code which isn't supposed to run is run", which is exactly what was asked for!

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own custom exception class by extending the Exception class.

For example:

```
class CustomException extends Exception {
    ...
}
```

And then:

```
if (stuff)
    doThings();
else if (something) 
    doOtherThings();
else if (otherStuff) 
    doStuff();
else
    throw new CustomException();
```